# Is there any way to tell exactly what files a command is accessing?

Tags: files, resources

I'm working on a piece of software that requires me to know what files and resources any certain launched process are accessing.

I'm not planning on attempting to track what every single script, application, and daemon is accessing, just a certain process provided by the user.

Is there any way to do this in Python (or any other language for that matter)? I'm going to do some research of my own, I just figured I'd ask here in case there are knowledgeable users out there who know about this sort of thing and can provide a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trace the [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) that a program makes. This is the usual method to find out what files it accesses. The tool to do this is called [`truss`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss_(Unix)) in many Unix systems, [`dtruss`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) on OSX, [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) on Linux. I'll describe Linux usage here; check the manual on other systems.

The simplest form is

```
strace myprogram arg1 arg2
```

This prints a log of all the system calls made by `myprogram`. ([Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160578/strace-hello-world-program).) To save the log in a file, use the option `-o`. To also log calls made by subprocesses, use the option `-f`. To select which system calls are logged, use the option `-e`. See the manual for details of what you can use as an argument to `-e`. For example, the following invocation logs file-related system calls (opening and closing, directory listing, etc.) except `read` and `write`.

```
strace -e'file,!read,!write' -o /tmp/myprogram.log -f myprogram arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Note that "processes" as meant by `strace -f` includes threads

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106220/check-for-open-files-with-python-in-linux), you can do it in python using the [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) module.  If you aren't limited to python, then [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) and [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) are the two command line utilities most commonly used for this purpose.

Comment: `psutil` or `lsof` are going to be *extremely* unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

The only completely-reliable way to do this is to trace system calls. The `strace` program (mentioned by @gowenfawr) does this correctly, and is implemented in terms of the `ptrace(2)` system call. Do note, however, that the `ptrace` call is difficult to use correctly; if you can't use `strace -e open` directly, consider the second way:

For most processes, you can instead intercept the calls to the C library `open` function via `LD_PRELOAD`. It is *trivial* for a hostile C program to avoid this, however; but if you trust a program not to do syscalls itself, it is simpler to implement than programmatic `ptrace`.

For a process that you know is written in a higher-level language such as python, you could instead intercept the high-level `open` calls, but this is likely to be more difficult than intercepting the C-level calls unless the language was designed to support such interception (python is not).

Finally - all of the above paragraphs are assuming files are opened with `open`. This is not always true, there is also `openat`, `open64`, `recvmsg` ancillary data, and inherited file descriptors from the parent.

Comment: Now, would this be safe to do via `subprocess.call('strace ....')` via the subprocess library in Python? Also, when you say intercept the call to `open`, how do I access LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness yes, `subprocess.call('strace ....')` is just fine, but do make sure you figure out how to separate the traced functions from the rest of the subprocess's stderr (`strace -o` is your friend). Also beware of threads, they require `-f`.

For `LD_PRELOAD`, look at http://www.zlibc.linux.lu/